# How to pass argument to batch file in ssh?

Tags: windows, macos, batch-file, ssh, sshpass

I am trying to run a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) on remote [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) machine, from [macos](/questions/tagged/macos) through [ssh](/questions/tagged/ssh) commands.

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh username@server < abc.bat
```

I want to send argument to my batch file.

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh username@server < abc.bat variable1
```

I get error

> ```
> 'variable1' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
> ```

In my batch file I want to read this `variable1` and pass it to one exe that I use as parameter.

```
set var1=%1
xyz.exe %var1%
```

Can someone help.

Comment: In your batch file you do not need to define a variable, just use `xyz.exe %1`. In future, please format the content of your questions, or answers, using the code and blockquote buttons as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Compo. i tried accessing the variable directly as well, but I am getting the error while i call the batch file with argument. Somehow argument is not getting recognised

Comment: Well, this does not execute `abc.bat`, it sends the text contents of `abc.bat` to `sshpass` via the _STDIN_ handle. Please [edit] the qurestion and exactly explain what you want…

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh username@server "abc.bat variable1"
```

That command will run `abc.bat` and provide `variable1` as the first argument.

However, be wary of chaining commands like `sshpass`.  In the following example,

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh username@server "abc.bat variable1"
```

will `"abc.bat variable1"` be an argument of `ssh` or `sshpass`??  I do not know, I do not use `sshpass`, but it is a confusion that can occur.